# Consider defining a bean of type 'backend.demo.test.test.filter.JwtRequestFilter' in your configuration

Tags: spring-boot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syOvg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTC3x.png)

How can I fix this bug, please help me !!

Comment: Pro tip: post your code and error messages as formatted text, not images

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.